# Why does Angular fetch data again when loaded in browser despite page already being prerendered?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have a simple route component:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppLandingComponent implements OnInit {
  
  private contentSignal = signal<MyQuery>(...);

  constructor(
    private apollo: SDKApollo,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    const id = this.route.snapshot.data.id;

    this.apollo.runQuery<MyQuery, MyQueryVariables>({
      client: 'cms',
      document: MyDocument,
      variables: {
        name: id
      }
    })
    .subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log('fetched data');
        this.contentSignal.set(data);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

That's set to being prerendered in `prerendered-routes.txt` which I point to in my project config:

```
        "prerender": {
          "discoverRoutes": false,
          "routesFile": "apps/foo/prerendered-routes.txt"
        },
```

`prerendered-routes.txt`:

```
/landing/foo
/landing/bar
```

Then I build the project which prerenders these two routes with content from the CMS I'm using. This works and when I navigate to these routes after serving the built project I can see in the network tab that I get prerendered HTML.

However, I also notice that it fetches the data again in the browser, which I don't understand. This defeats the whole purpose of using prerendering.

If I run the data fetching on the server only, then the page doesn't load correctly at all despite getting prerendered HTML.

Is this some prerendering quirk I'm not aware of and is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Are using v17 ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes, v17.0.7.

Comment: But you're not using the `ApolloClient` from `apollo-angular`?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler No, using `ApolloClient` directly from `@apollo/client/core`.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular [TransferCache](https://angular.dev/guide/ssr#caching-data-when-using-httpclient) doesn't work when the HTTP call isn't made by the `HttpClient`.

Also prerendering doesn't prevent `ngOnInit` from being called when the component is initialized on the client side.

Comment: So I need to use `createHttpLink` or something to tell `ApolloClient` to use `HttpClient` instead?